# Clarity needed for indexOf method for Vector class java

Tags: java, api, vector, controls

I have a Vector object with String elements of varying content with size about 10,000 elements in the Vector object. So instead of looping like a mad man, I'm thinking of using indexOf to get the first occurrence. For simplicity:

```
String curNode = "0";
Vector<String> stringVec = "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "0", "1";
```

Based on Vector API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), if I do the following:

```
int firstOccur = stringVec.indexOf(curNode);
```

Is it guaranteed to give me `firstOccur=3` ?
Also, I'm not quite sure if String being an immutable object, or any violation of the `equals` method comes into play here.

Comment: 2 things -- `indexOf()` will be looping anyways, just hidden away, and it's generally a better idea to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this vector, or -1 if this vector does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

That is directly from the api. `.indexOf` will guaranteed return the first instance of the object in the `Vector`, or a `-1` should the object not be found in the `Vector`. From my knowledge, index calls `.equals()` on the objects, not the `==` operator. So there should be no violations from `Strings` being immutable.